# Algorithm for Items Best Fit/Arangement in a Box

Tags: algorithms

I was looking for an algorithm that will give the best fit arrangement of package items in a box. For example given a large box and various items with multiple shapes(can be rectangle, square and so on and so forth), how will I arrange the items so that it will fit in the box? DO we have already an algorithm for that? If yes, what algorithm is it?

If no, I was thinking of making an algorithm for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are plenty of algorithms.

Here are some existing literature about packing rectangles.

- [What algorithm can be used for packing rectangles of different sizes into the smallest rectangle possible in a fairly optimal way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1213394)
- [Pack rectangular objects of different sizes in a fixed size rectangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891437/)
- [Approximation Algorithms for Rectangle Packing Problems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07851.pdf).
- [Optimal rectangle packing](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2f2e/26e9e7b1e86dd44e0c42c13d58f37d1d64dd.pdf).

Here are some libraries that can be used readily.

- [Python 2D rectangle packing library](https://github.com/secnot/rectpack)
- [Rectangle packing program](https://github.com/Penlect/rectangle-packer)
- [Github topic on packing algorithms](https://github.com/topics/packing-algorithm)